# How to set image loader in windows phone?

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, image-loading

Hi i am developing windows phone app.I need to set image loader.i tried low profile image loader but i can't get any changes.Any one please let me know how to set image loader.

I need to solve another one. I have product name it was text wrapped but the text goes to hide right side, didn't wrapped the text

I am using code given below.

```
<Image delay:LowProfileImageLoader.UriSource="{Binding ProductImage}" Width="189" Height="170" Name="value"  Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

This is text wrapping code

```
<StackPanel   VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="3">
            <ListBox x:Name="ProductLists" ItemsSource="{Binding Product}" Margin="5,5,5,0"  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" SelectionChanged="ProductList_SelectionChanged" SelectionMode="Single">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <Border  Background="White"  Margin="10,5,8,0">
                            <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" Width="900" Background="White" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="5,20,0,20">

                                    <Image delay:LowProfileImageLoader.UriSource="{Binding ProductImage}" Width="189" Height="170" Name="value"  Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="Product" FontWeight="Bold" Padding="20,0,0,0"  TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Foreground="#000000" Text="{Binding ProductName}" ></TextBlock>
                                        <TextBlock  Padding="20,10,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  FontFamily="Arial"  Foreground="#a2a2a2" Text="Price Range"  ></TextBlock>
                                        <Grid>
                                            <TextBlock Text="&#163;" Padding="20,10,0,0"   FontFamily="Arial" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#232323"  Height="31" />
                                            <TextBlock x:Name="PPrice" Padding="40,10,0,0" FontWeight="Bold"  FontFamily="Arial" Foreground="#000000" Text="{Binding Price}" ></TextBlock>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
            <Grid Height="220"></Grid>
        </StackPanel>
```

I got result given below image

[image]

I want to result like given below image

[image]

Any one tell me how to do this?

Comment: Ya i tried already what you said, i got the same result

Comment: I used this normal code: <Image Source="{Binding ProductImage}"  Width="190" Height="200" Name="value"  Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="20,0,0,0"></Image>